# Rspec, factory_girl - Test create action with model with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying write a rspec test for a action create. The controller is OrderController.
The Order model has many line items. I don't know how I can do this call:

post :create, order: FactoryGirl.build(:order).attributes

But this fail because my validation, that, says: Order should have at least ONE line items. I think that I should create a order that have line item.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you're asking can be done (build Order with LineItems...). But it won't solve your problem. Because the #attributes you're calling will not include line items in the returning hash. You should use literal hash or generate it through a helper functional if needed. I don't think it is sensible to use FactoryGirl here (at least from the context I see).

Answer (score 1):

You can define associations in factory_girl.

```
factory :order_line do
    #some attributes

    order
end

factory :order do
    #some attributes        

    #the line's count you want to create
    ignore do
      lines_count 5
    end

    after(:create) do |order, evaluator|
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:order_line, evaluator.lines_count, order: order)
    end
end
```

So, when you create an order using factory_girl, you will build some lines too.

Comment: @User426891 The above is taken from https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations, which you can consult for more information on FactoryGirl.

Answer (score 1):

You can build associated objects with FactoryGirl. Nevertheless, you have two options:

1.) Manual/explicit approach - here you pass line_items into factory call:

```
FactoryGirl.build(:order, line_items: [build(:line_item), build(:line_item)]
```

2.) Automatic approach - you configure factory to always include at least one line item:

In your factories file:

```
factory :order do
  # attrs

  after :build do |order, ev|
    order.line_items << build(:line_item)
  end 
end
```

This will work for building one default line_item with default attributes. If you want to have more specific attributes, you must fall back to using the first approach.